# How can I easily peel baby round potatoes?

Tags: potatoes, roasting, peeling

I was planning to try out a recipe for roasted baby potatoes, but I have noticed that most of the recipes involve slicing the baby potatoes in half and roasting them with their skins on. They turn out this way:

[image: https://www.weightwatchers.com/us/recipe/roasted-baby-potatoes-oregano-and-lemon-1/5626a63ca6d5b39610701a16]

However, I want to peel them and roast so they turn out like **crispy, roasted potato *balls*.**

[image: Some branded potatoes]

Does anyone know how to appropriately peel baby round potatoes bought fresh and with skins from the market?

I thought of blanching them and then pulling their skins off, but I'm not sure if they will work well with this variety.

(*The above image is from https://www.weightwatchers.com/us/recipe/roasted-baby-potatoes-oregano-and-lemon-1/5626a63ca6d5b39610701a16*)

Comment: It's perfectly feasible to peel them with a regular vegetable peeler.

Comment: The industrial process used to peel the potato is not something easily duplicated at home due to the pressures and temperatures involved. The machines cause the skin to separate from the underlying layers with steam. If you are using a regular peeler you could do it if you want but it is a whole lot of work.

Comment: Did you by any chance ever try blanching? I'm curious how well it'd work, and you can totally answer your own question if it does!

Comment: Try blanching and see how easily the skins come off.

Answer (score 1):

As the skins are quite thin, use a (new) green kitchen scrubber.  This would give the same result as the potato peeling bowl for a Kenwood, and a whole lot cheaper.  Enjoy your potatoes...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually, tiny potatoes are used unpeeled (probably because it would take so much trouble to peel them). If you want to peel the potatoes, select very large ones so the peeling is easier. Then chop up the potato into smaller dice.